# Multiple search IDs in a single search textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a single search textbox where I would like to enter at least 20 Employee IDs Separated by period or comma and look up the Employees Name from a Table and populate all the Matching Employee name in a Gridview. Is there is any helpful link or suggestions on this ?

Comment: You didn't give any detail about the tables. Is that a SQL database or something else? What do you need? The SQL query? You should give more details about your situation and what you have tried. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's a SQL Database, I believe our input parameter in Store Procedure will be the same @EmployeeID regardless of the number of searchstring that we are passing, and I do have query.. It would be helpful to know more about the Code behind ...It's easier to search one employee name based on one EmployeeID but I am not sure how to implement that for multiple.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? With SQL server you can use dynamic SQL, so you could pass whole list as nvarchar and use EmployeeID IN ([list that you passed]). From code behind, you can split list of IDs and use foreach to call the procedure and populate data. Not sure what way do you want to do it?

Comment: See [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](//stackoverflow.com/q/878833)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a stored procedure that accepts a parameter called @EmployeeIds and the CSV list that was passed to the server code and stored procedure has been checked, then in the where clause put:

```
WHERE ',' + @EmployeeIds + ',' LIKE '%,' + RTRIM(LTRIM(EmployeeID)) + ',%'
```

Comment: The parameter should be `@EmployeeIds` or `@EmployeeIdList`. Otherwise, it would be misleading. And of course, if should be a `varchar` instead of an `int`. BTW, `EmployeeID` should be an `int`, why the trimming?

Comment: The trim removes any whitespace that may have been mistakingly added to the text during data entry. The where clause I gave you let's you pass a csv list into the stored procedure and match it with employee IDs.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But again, the DB field should be an `int`, so you can't trim that. Your IDs in the DB should always be properly set. If for some reason they are a `varchar`, they should definitely not have any weird spaces surrounding it. You still need to edit that "@EmployeeId" in the first sentence.

Comment: The poster never said the column data type. If it's an int then removed the trims and cast it to a varchar.